# Check if a new Woocommerce attribute is being added

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

How can I check if a new Woocommerce attribute is being added?
I need to edit the slug whenever an attribute is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use [`woocommerce_attribute_added`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_attribute.html#467) action hook located in [`wc_create_attribute()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_attribute.html#381-532) function, that is **triggered when adding a new product attribute**. You will be able to get the attribute slug like in this example:

```
/**
 * Attribute added (hook).
 *
 * @param int   $id   Added attribute ID.
 * @param array $data Attribute data.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', 'attribute_added_action_callback', 10, 2 );
function attribute_added_action_callback( $id, $data ) {

    $attribute_name = $data['attribute_label']; // <== The name
    $attribute_slug  = $data['attribute_name']; // <== The slug
}
```

If you need to update the attribute data follow the way that is done inside [`wc_create_attribute()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_attribute.html#381-532) function (that uses WordPress [`WPDB`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) class and methods), looking to [its source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_attribute.html#381-532).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, but I need to change the slug before it is inserted, I need the slug to go without the "-", for example "Title with space" would have the slug "Titlewithspace"

Comment: I think I was wrong in the description, not when an attribute is added, but a term to the attribute